# Can I apply for a German Blue Card with a Data Analyst/Data Science job?

Tags: germany

I read that Blue Card salary thresholds are lower for mathematicians, scientists, IT professionals and doctors. Does this include Data Science/Data Analyst jobs? I have a Masters degree in Economics, oriented towards econometrics and statistics.

Comment: *I read that Blue Card salary thresholds...*  Can you add the reference, so people can research from there if necessary?

Comment: The lower salary requirement is true. See for example http://www.makeitingermany.de. Your job description (the title is not very relevant) needs to roughly be aligned with your degree, and your uni as well as the degree you got there needs to be listed in the European something (I forgot what it's called) database for universities as accredited. The rest is up to the job centre and the foreigners office of the town that you will be moving to. Both of those get your application passed on from the embassy (unless you can enter the country already, because then you can apply there in person)